# Issue with window cocoa xib

Tags: macos, cocoa, xib

I am working on a MAc osx application. I have created a window with different views: Scroll view, tab view etc., I have an issue with the window created. If I run the application,

First time - window is created as per the dimensions given in the XIB.

Second time - If I stop it, and run it again,  the window is compressed - table view compressed. and thereby every other item is not at the right place.

Third time - And If I run it again, then it all looks fine, like it was at First time.

Fourth time - Corrupted like that of second time.

...Like this, I am getting wierd window output at alternate times.

Please help!!